# Merchant account not found braintree

Tags: android, paypal, braintree

I am trying to implement `paypal` using custom ui of braintree, server side code is in `node.js` but always getting **Merchant account not found** error. I am describing the steps how I implement paypal using braintree:

1. I am generating client token and customer id in `braintree vault`.
2. Using that token I am initializing BraintreeFragment.
3. In button click I am getting that error.

Here is the code snippet

Manifest

```
<activity android:name="com.braintreepayments.api.BraintreeBrowserSwitchActivity"
  android:launchMode="singleTask">
  <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
      <data android:scheme="${applicationId}.braintree" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Gradle

```
compile ('com.braintreepayments.api:drop-in:3.+') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'cardview-v7'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'customtabs'
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'design'
}
compile 'com.braintreepayments:browser-switch:0.1.4'
```

In `onCreate` I am requesting my server for `client token` after I get client token from server initializing `BraintreeFragment` like this

```
mBraintreeFragment = BraintreeFragment.newInstance(context, braintreeToken);
```

In button click I am using this code

```
if (mBraintreeFragment != null) {
      PayPalRequest request = new PayPalRequest().localeCode("US").billingAgreementDescription("Your agreement description");
      PayPal.requestBillingAgreement(mBraintreeFragment, request);
      PayPal.authorizeAccount(mBraintreeFragment);
}
```

After that I got the error and it is not redirect to webview. If I use static client token(from braintree's site's demo token) then it is working fine.

> Note: I already linked paypal merchant account in Braintree's account also
>   used the pulic key, private key from Braintree's control panel before implementing the client side.

[image]

generate client token code

```
gateway.clientToken.generate({}, function (err, response) {
    if (!err) {
         if (response.clientToken.length > 0) {
               gateway.customer.create({
                  id: statusData.response_data._id
         },function(err,result) {
             if(!err){

             }
         })

      }
   }

});
```

Comment: Please share a snippet of how you're generating the client token on your server.

Comment: @Shea please check I have updated the question

Comment: @Kaushik have you solved your issue? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: No didn't find the fix

Comment: I have the same Issue. 
I generate token in this way `BraintreeGateway(Environment.SANDBOX,<merchantId>,<Public Key>,<Private Key>).clientToken().generate()`